# Selecting a single rows based on two columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following data:

[image: MyData]

I am not sure whether the image is pasted properly or not but I will paste the data as well, bear with me, please.

```
ID  AccountCodeID   CarrierServiceID    Priority    IsDefault
173    480                72                1             1
176    480                71                0             0
177    481                 4                0             0
```

From the above result I only want to select one row for **AccountCodeID 480** based on IsDefault and Priority column values.

When **IsDefault** is **TRUE** (1) then I want to select that row, else I want to select row that has the Priority 0 (0 being high priority when default is not specified).

Is this possible from one single query?  If so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, etc?

Comment: I cannot edit the question now but I cannot say where AccountCodeId = 480 because it should return single row for all the AccountCodeIDs based on the condition.  That is why I need to aggregate the result but not sure how and group by won't help me with my little knowledge.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 with SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For almost anything except MySQL...

```
WITH
  prioritised AS
(
  SELECT
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountCodeCarrierID_FK
                           ORDER BY IsDefault DESC, Priority ASC
                      ) 
                        AS priorityOrder
  FROM
    yourTable
) 
SELECT
  *
FROM
  prioritised
WHERE
  priorityOrder = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
 Select Top 1 from Table1 order by IsDefault DESC, Priority ASC
```

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot use Top 1 here because there are multiple accounts